# Signup/Contribution pages render forms with double County and Country dropdown selectors

Tags: civimember, contributions, forms

Signup/Contribution pages render forms with double County and Country dropdown selectors. How di I remove the redundant ones?
[image]

Comment: Can you check if the page has any JS errors? It may be because some JS must be conflicting with CiviCRM JS.

Comment: There is some Javascript which converts a normal dropdown to a seleect2 dropdown. It does this by creating the select2 element and hide the original drop down. It looks like the hiding part is failing. Why that is? I dont know. But it is probably caused by a JS error maybe somewhere else on the page or site.